# PHP Graph libraries not working

Tags: php, jpgraph, pchart

I have installed pchart as well as Jpgraph on my system but on running their example sites all I get is a blank page. GD has been already installed on my system and I have checked it already. Do I need to change anything in the php.ini file?

Comment: do you have error reporting on? checked the php error logs?

Comment: no error just nothing getting diplayed

Comment: It's not at all clear what you've tried so far. What code have you run? What would you expect it to do and what does it actually give you?

Comment: I am using libraries like Jpgraph and pchart. They have a set of examples. I am storing a test.php file in the same folder and it is working fine. But none of the default examples provided  by the library are working. Only an en empty page is displayed whereas some kind of a graph was expected

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the GD2 library in PHP. In the PHP.INI look for the line;

```
extensions=php_gd2.dll
```

and remove the ; (semi-colon) at the beginning of the line. after you save that file you will need to restart Apache (or whatever you use) for the changes to take effect.

References came from this page; http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/gd-support.php